# Why is my if condition not working to call my injected controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, if-statement, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to auto generate an ID if no reference ID was found in database and not generate and overwrite if existing reference ID is found but with my code its not working please help me I am new and still learning.

My if else condition code is not working I need to call `_sysautoController` if reference is null or no reference ID.

I have tried this code:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult ConfirmDetails(RTSLIST Model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Reference))
        {
            _sysautoController.Index(1, Model.IdNo);
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Well, if you stop this code in the debugger, what *is* the value of `Model.Reference`? What *exactly* do you mean by "not working" - what happens?

Comment: ...are you injecting `Controllers` **into** other `Controllers`? If so, then your project is incorrectly designed: you should only inject _services_, not entire other Controllers...)